# Filter Twitter feeds only by language

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am using Tweepy API for extracting Twitter feeds. I want to extract all Twitter feeds of a specific language only. The language filter works only if `track` filter is provided. The following code returns 406 error:

```
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(languages=["en"])
```

How can I extract **all** the tweets from certain language using Tweepy?

Comment: Have you solved this issue. I also want to extract specific language tweet like japanese.

Answer (score 28):

You can't (without special access). Streaming **all** the tweets (unfiltered) requires a connection to [the firehose](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/firehose), which is granted only in specific use cases by Twitter. Honestly, the firehose isn't really necessary--proper use of [`track`](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track) can get you more tweets than you know what to do with.

Try using something like this:

```
stream.filter(languages=["en"], track=["a", "the", "i", "you", "u"]) # etc
```

Filtering by words like that will get you many, many tweets. If you want real data for the most-used words, check out this article from Time: [The 500 Most Frequently Used Words on Twitter](http://techland.time.com/2009/06/08/the-500-most-frequently-used-words-on-twitter/). You can use [up to 400](https://twittercommunity.com/t/streaming-api-limit/8707) keywords, but that will likely approach the 1% limit of tweets at a given time interval. If your `track` parameter matches 60% of all tweets at a given time, you will still only get 1% (which is a LOT of tweets).

Comment: Thanks!!
I was typing `stream.filter(lang=["en"], track=["something"])`

Answer (score 8):

Try `lang='en'` param in `Cursor()`  e.g.

`tweepy.Cursor(.. lang='en')`

Answer (score 4):

Other than getting filtered tweets directly, you can filter it after getting all tweets of different languages by:

```
tweets = api.search("python")
for tweet in tweets:
   if tweet.lang == "en":
      print(tweet.text)
      #Do the stuff here
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the arguments for the track method in the github code https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py

Put languages in a array of ISO_639-1_codes.

They are:

```
filter(self, follow=None, track=None, is_async=False, locations=None,
               stall_warnings=False, languages=None, encoding='utf8', filter_level=None):
```

So to track by languages just put:

```
class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        j = json.loads(data)
        t = {
          'screenName' : j['user']['screen_name'],
          'text:': j['text']
          }
        print(t)
        return(True)

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

stream = Stream(auth=auth, listener=Listener(),wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

stream.filter(track=['Trump'],languages=["en","fr","es"])
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tweepy search](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html) allows to fetch tweets for specific language. You can use ISO 639-1 code to specify the value for language parameter.
Following code will fetch tweets with full text in specified language (English for below example)

```
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    tweets = api.search(q = keywordtosearch, lang = 'en', count = 100, truncated = False, tweet_mode = 'extended')
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.full_text)
        #add your code
```

Comment: tried your code, got `AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'`

Comment: replace search with search_tweets

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
a=input("Enter Tag: ")
tweets = api.search(a, count=200)
a=[]
for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.lang == "en":
        a.append(tweet.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of GetOldTweets3 (https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/), you can download tweets (even old ones) by filtering over few criteria, as shown below:

```
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('Coronavirus')\
                                       .setSince("2020-02-15")\
                                       .setUntil("2020-03-29")\
                                       .setMaxTweets(5)\
                                       .setNear('India')\
                                       .setLang('en')
tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.date)
    print(tweet.geo)
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.permalink)
    print(tweet.username)
    print(tweet.retweets)
    print(tweet.favorites)
    print(tweet.mentions)
    print(tweet.hashtags)
    print('*'*50)
```